# Vite Dev server TypeError

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am trying to migrate a CRA app to Vite and have run into the following issue:
I'm using a custom wrapper for the portable-fetch module that looks like this

```
import * as realFetch from 'portable-fetch';
import { locCommon as loc } from '../localisation/LocalisationStore';
import { LocalisationUtils } from '../localisation/LocalisationUtils';

/**
 * Custom wrapper around fetch call from 'portable-fetch' module that examines http headers
 * and if header AppConstants.HttpHeaderCultureCode is found, language is set to one provided in this header.
 *
 * @param url url to be called
 * @param init initial parameters
 */
export function portableFetch(url: string, init?: any): Promise<Response> {
    let promise: Promise<Response> = realFetch(url, init);
    promise.then((response) => {
        if (response.headers) {
            let cultureCode = LocalisationUtils.getCultureCodeFromHttpHeader(response.headers);
            if (cultureCode) {
                loc.changeCultureCode(cultureCode);
            }
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

This is transpiled by Vite into JS that looks like this:

```
import __vite__cjsImport0_portableFetch from "/node_modules/.vite/deps/portable-fetch.js?v=77e91fc1"; const realFetch = ((m) => m?.__esModule ? m : { ...(typeof m === 'object' && !Array.isArray(m) ? m : {}), default: m })(__vite__cjsImport0_portableFetch);
import { locCommon as loc } from "/@fs/C:/../Common/dist/localisation/LocalisationStore.js";
import { LocalisationUtils } from "/@fs/C:/../Common/dist/localisation/LocalisationUtils.js";
/**
 * Custom wrapper around fetch call from 'portable-fetch' module that examines http headers
 * and if header AppConstants.HttpHeaderCultureCode is found, language is set to one provided in this header.
 *
 * @param url url to be called
 * @param init initial parameters
 */
export function portableFetch(url, init) {
    var promise = realFetch(url, init);
    promise.then(function (response) {
        if (response.headers) {
            var cultureCode = LocalisationUtils.getCultureCodeFromHttpHeader(response.headers);
            if (cultureCode) {
                loc.changeCultureCode(cultureCode);
            }
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Upon loading the page, I am greeted with 'Uncaught TypeError: realFetch is not a function' in console.

I think it has something to do with Vite dependency pre-bundling, but other than that, no clue what is going wrong.